# The probability of correctly guessing babies' sexes

Tags: probability

Imagine you were attempting to correctly guess the sex of the baby for 50,000 pregnant women.

Is there any particular strategy that would give you better results? For example should you choose all girls?

In other words, would your success rate be affected if the each time you guessed it was a random guess?

Answer (score 0):

For assigning the sex to a each woman's child - no strategy whatsoever.

Your success rate would not be effected by each guess in any way.

This is of course assuming each sex is equally likely, which I think is what you mean too.

Answer (score 0):

In short: yes, it would be worse. You are better off guessing for the gender with higher probability (so probably girl).

long answer: assume that all events are i.i.d. In this case, you always have the same chance of the baby being a girl. Assume for simplicity p(G=female) > p(G=male).

every time you choose G=female, you have a chance of p(G=male) to make an error. Every time you choose G=male, you have a change of p(G=female) of making an error. Thus always choosing G=female minimizes you probability of error in every single guess and thus in the whole dataset.

Comment: If the probability of a girl is greater in this question, then the question is trivial to the point of no reasonable person asking it.

Comment: In reality, the probability of a male child is greater (rougly 52% chance.)

Comment: @ Kundor oh yes. Thanks for the correction. I had 51.5% in my head but got the gender wrong.

@Doop I think this is a valid question: even smart computer scientist students ask this in our machine learning course.

Comment: I think it is a valid question when the sexes are equally likely, and is more likely what the OP was asking, or at least that's the feel I got from his "in other words." If one is more likely than the other then of course there is a strategy - keep picking the more likely one.